# Boxes with two different border widths

Tags: boxes, mdframed

I'm making a box with text inside. For it I use the package `mdframed`.   Essentially I want a box with the left border width 2pt and the rest of the borders width 1pt.

What I've got so far:

```
\newmdenv[
topline=false,
rightline=false,
bottomline=false,
linewidth=2pt,]{txtbox}
```

Comment: Are you sticking to `mdframed` or will `tcolorbox` be a solution too -- you can control every rule width of the box separately within `tcolorbox`, perhaps this possible with `mdframed` too

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't know `tcolorbox`, but I'll try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the `tcolorbox` style to make such a framed box, where I exaggerated the left rule width a little bit, as a demo...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=1pt,leftrule=5pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc]
\blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will update this solution with the more generic `\newtcolorbox` command later on

Comment: Why not add the `\tcbset` option as well then? `:-)`

Comment: @1010011010: I am in a hurry for another solution ... to another question :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your solution ;)

Comment: How do I set the default `boxrule` in my preamble for all the boxes?